# In this driven double pendulum what would be the position of the proximal arm relative to $x$-axis when stopper loses contact with the peripheral arm?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram

In the images below I have drawn a double pendulum system with the pivot hub and a stopper A which is imagined to be fixed to some large wall. In both scenarios 1 and 2  the system is initially at rest and there is a wedge and square stopper fixed at the end of the proximal arm to prevent clockwise rotation.

Both frictionless pivots and stoppers are assumed to have negligible mass.

The proximal arm is a rigid rod whose mass is w and not negligible.

The peripheral arm is assumed to be a thin rigid rod with a non negligible mass m attached to its end.

Let's assume that both systems are set in motion by the same torque T applied at the central pivot hub.

I have attempted to draw all the forces when the system is set in motion by torque T for both scenarios:

Tangential forces F1 and F2.

Centripetal forces C1 and C2.

Stopper reaction force R1 and R2 (at a point d/2) whose line of force
will be through the stopper COM.

Weight of proximal and peripheral arms wg and mg.

Tension force S1 and S2 in the peripheral arm for scenarios 1 and 2.

Question:  For both scenarios 1 and 2 , how would I be able to determine the angle the proximal arm makes with the +x axis at the exact point when the peripheral arm loses contact with the stoppers?

Please note that I'm not insisting on a mathematical proof and would be happy with just an intuitive explanation as to why the peripheral arm might lose contact with the stopper earlier/later (or maybe identical) relative to the position of the proximal arm angle made with the +x axis.

[image]

Comment: I added the tension forces S1 and S2 so edited my comment and diagram. I also added a comment in my original question to say that I'd be satisfied with just an intuitive explanation than some rigorous mathematical proof.  This is not homework but related to my hobby studying the biomechanics of the golf swing.

Comment: How is the proximal arm connected to the double pendulum?

Comment: Hi John - its just another frictionless pivot P2 in the 1st diagram. So P1 pivot is fixed to a wall while P2 is just like the linked image .https://www.tutelman.com/golf/swing/golfSwingPhysics/swing.gif

Comment: The triangular and square wedges in scenario 1 and 2 are fixed to the  proximal arm to stop the peripheral arm from jackknifing (rotating clockwise).

Comment: None of the scenarios above can be at rest. This is because the combined center of mass needs to be directly under the pivot for the system to be at rest. I feel like there is more to this that is not shared.

Comment: I've missed a force/torque applied by stopper A on the proximal arm.  I should have also said stopper A's mass is not negligible but didn't think it was relevant because its fixed to the wall and won't be involved once a torque about P1 sets the system in motion.

Comment: What? Please [edit] the question to add relevant information.

Comment: Just done so - I hope I've got this right now as I am poor at drawing force diagrams (stopper A is fixed to the wall and provides the force/torque to keep the system initially at rest).

Comment: Is the proximal arm pivoted on the bottom at p1? To do a proper free-body diagram you need to show the parts at a _displaced_ position with small positive angles and displacements.

Comment: Yes the proximal arm is pivoted at p1. Unsure how to figure out the small angle displacements as this is the problem I am trying to figure out . As the proximal arm moves anti-clockwise, will the peripheral arm lose contact with the wedge sooner or later in scenario 1 (acute angle beta) vs scenario 2  where the starting angle is 90. degrees.

Comment: You might want to look at https://blog.rectorsquid.com/linkage-mechanism-designer-and-simulator/ in order to work out the kinematics of the situation.

Comment: Many thanks . All I was trying to do was replicate the starting position of this golf robot PingMan . https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KbmRLaNF3qM

Comment: Maybe I understand better now. it is a double pendulum, and the equations are those of a double compound pendulum (where mass quantity, center of mass, and mass moment of inertia matter). In your case, there is a limit on the relative angle between the two links which define the rest positions. Is this correct?

Comment: Is [this a representation](https://i.imgur.com/ICoU6G9.png) of the mechanism?

Comment: Your interpretation is not exactly the same as mine. The wedge at the top is part of the proximal arm , not the peripheral arm. Many thanks for spending your time trying to help me and I imagine the general solution is probably too complex (probably beyond my grade although I am 65 yrs old).

Comment: So it looks more like this: https://i.imgur.com/CW31Jwg.png

Comment: Yes , that's it exactly. And for the 2nd scenario the beta angle would be 90 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of your question is as follows:

[image: fig1]

We do a static analysis to find the stopper forces $R_x$ and $R_y$ when a torque $\tau_1$ is applied.

- Proximal Arm

  $$ \begin{aligned}
   Fx_1 - R_x - Fx_2 & = 0 \\
   Fy_1 - R_y - Fy_2 - m_1 g & = 0 \\
   \tau_1 + (r_1-d_1) R_x - r_1 Fx_2 &= 0 \\
  \end{aligned}$$
- Peripheral Arm

  $$ \begin{aligned}
   R_x + Fx_2 & = 0 \\
   Fy_2 + R_y - m_2 g &= 0 \\
   d_1 \tan \beta R_y - \ell_2 m_2 g \tan \beta + d_1 R_x &= 0 
  \end{aligned}$$

The static solutions to the above force balance equations are

$$\begin{aligned}
  Fx_1 &= 0 \\
  Fy_1 &= (m_1 + m_2) g \\
  Fx_2 & = \frac{\tau_1}{d_1-2 r_1}\\
  Fy_2 & = m_2 g + \frac{\tau \cot \beta}{d_1-2 r_1} - \frac{\ell m_2 g}{d_1} \\
  R_x & = \frac{\tau_1}{d_1  - 2 r_1}\\
  R_y & = \frac{\tau_1 \cot \beta}{d_1  - 2 r_1} + \frac{\ell_2 m_2 g}{d_1} \\
\end{aligned}$$

The conditions for the stop to be active are $R_x>0$ and $R_y>0$

But once motion is involved the above equations are no longer valid, because you have to consider the dynamics of the situation (acceleration of the center of mass) and the general solution would be too long to write out here.